# Create custom consent form for AdMob

Tags: android, react-native, admob

Is it possible to create a custom consent form for AdMob instead of using the default AdMob form?

I ask because the default is very limited in style and doesn't look user friendly.
As I remember, some time ago there was an option to create your own form - not sure if there is such option with User Messaging Platform.